# Bcache hangs on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ext4, bcache

I successfully setup my system to use bache in /home partition (200GB SSD partition as cache for 500 GB HDD partition). However, I keep receiving these messages:

```
INFO: task bcache_writebac:222 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Tainted: PF          O 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
bcache_writebac D ffff88021fc94440     0   222      2 0x00000000
ffff88003623feb8 0000000000000002 ffff880035e097f0 ffff88003623ffd8
0000000000014440 0000000000014440 ffff880035e097f0 ffff880210341d80
ffff880035e10000 ffffffffa00be840 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Call Trace:
[<ffffffffa00be840>] ? read_dirty+0x400/0x400 [bcache]
[<ffffffff81719ee9>] schedule+0x29/0x70
[<ffffffff8108b2ed>] kthread+0xad/0xf0
[<ffffffff8108b240>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
[<ffffffff817263fc>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[<ffffffff8108b240>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
```

Besides my feat its causing my some data loss, it seems to be preventing me to have a clear shut down.